# Angular modal service doesn't recognize the templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, service, modal-dialog

> https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service

When I want to show the modal, the console show this error

`GET http://localhost:3000/copy/duplicate_view.html 404 (Not Found)`

**on the controller:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  function editCtrl($scope, appSettings,pricingService, ModalService) {

    $scope.show = function() {
      ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: '../copy/duplicate_view.html',
        controller: "DialogDemoCtrl"
      })
    };
  }

  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('editCtrl', editCtrl)
  ;
})();
```

**On the HTML:**

```
 <a class="btn-green-alt btn" href ng-click="show()">{{'dialog.EXPORT' | translate}}</a>
```

**at Dependency**

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'daterangepicker',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'ui.tinymce',
    'angularModalService'
  ])
```

And this is what i see on the service's code...

```
  var getTemplate = function getTemplate(template, templateUrl) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (template) {
      deferred.resolve(template);
    } else if (templateUrl) {
      $templateRequest(templateUrl, true).then(function (template) {
        deferred.resolve(template);
      }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
      });
    } else {
      deferred.reject("No template or templateUrl has been specified.");
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

Comment: Could you please add the data structure of your project.

Comment: I already edited my question

Comment: I was referring to your files directory, because of the error you are facing this may be related to the route of your duplicate_view.html file.

Comment: no no no.. the route it's fine.
even if a duplicate the view and put it on the same directory as the controller and change the templateUrl for 'templateUrl: duplicate_view.html' the console show the same error

Answer (score 0):

Set absolute path to your template whitout using `..`

**EDIT**
*Based on your comment about the project structure*

```
app
  specifications
    copy
      duplicate_view.html
```

Then set `templateUrl` as follow

```
templateUrl: 'app/specifications/copy/duplicate_view.html',
```

Comment: it doesn't work ... show the same error but different route

Comment: where is located `duplicate_view.html` ?

Comment: app > specifications >copy (inside copy: duplicate_view)

Comment: I have edited my answer.. did you try `templateUrl: 'app/specifications/copy/duplicate_view.html',`